# autocompletion removes the \ in the beginning of latex code

Tags: auto-completion

https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1527

a work around for problems with auto complete in ST4

hopefully of some use to other users

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this a solution or a question?  Is the question behind the link you've posted?  Please put the question here.  Is the solution in the text of the image you've posted?  Please type that as an answer.  Or is something else going on?

Comment: it is a solution for a problem i was facing with auto complete

Comment: In that case, rewrite the question to **have the form of an actual question**, then post a self-answer that contains the answer. (by the way don't just include images, post the actual text.)